# Django architechture, web and worker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, optimization

My application consists of two parts,

The **worker process** parses through data from an external API, doing computations and storing the information.

The **web process** looks up the data stored by the worker and displays it. However, this is a performance/optimization problem.

The web process looks up one table in the database, which consists of 4 fields. However it needs to do foreignkey lookups on 3 different fields to get all the information it needs. Now the database foreignkey lookups are quite slow (> 1M rows in the other 3 tables), whereas the main lookup table has < 10K rows, so fetching all the foreignkeys are very fast.

Should I store all the information needed in the main table instead of having foreignkeys to other tables for performance? Considering one write is happening every 5 seconds, while ~200 clients are accessing roughly every 30 seconds.

I've tried to cache the results in a rediscache, but that was just as slow as before - as the value of each key gets quite big.

Any ideas on how to structure this otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

How do you make the query? Take a look a this: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related](https://web.archive.org/web/20190801231321/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)